# Admob ads not working (Test ads work fine but ads with real id don't show up)

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Test ads work fine but Real ads not working. The app is live on play store but the ads are not showing up on any device and now its been a week and still the same thing. I have tried each and every way I found on StackOverflow but still, it's not working.

I have put these in Manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_ad_id"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
```

Initialized in Splash

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this,getString(R.string.app_ad_id));
```

Ad Tag in the layout

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

Displaying the ad:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest bannerAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(bannerAdRequest);
```

Now please tell me that where I'm wrong.

Comment: Check your email for any violation of admob policies.

Comment: Its not working before the app was not published.. and the ads are working fine on other applications .

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but - have you connected the app on the Admob website to the published app? Maybe you have created the app first in Admob and forget to connect it to the real one after publishing it in google play?

Comment: Is it necessary? as in previous applications, the ads started working even before publishing the application.

Comment: I think it is `getResources().getString()` rather than bare `getString()`

Comment: Thanks to all of you. The issue with Admob acccount. I had conflict with my boss as he was saying that there is no issue with the admob account and finally after trying with another admob, the ads started working. So basically, I won. By the way, Thanks for your precious times. :)